# How do I secure LDAP Realm Definitions in Tomcat's server.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, ldap

In order to have my J2EE webapp to authenticate via Active directory, I need to modify both the app's web.xml file and the Server's server.xml file.

Someone raised the concern that within server.xml the LDAP credentials are store in plain text, as the example  below:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
    connectionName="CN=LDAPSERVER,OU=MON,OU=ServiceAccount,OU=Exchange 2003,DC=DOMAIN"
    connectionPassword="secret"
    connectionURL="ldap://myLDAPhost-xxx:389"
    alternateURL="ldap://myLDAPhost-xxx:389"
    referrals="follow"
    userBase="OU=USERGROUP,DC=DOMAIN"
    userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
    userSubtree="true"
    userRoleName="memberOf"
<Realm/>
```

Is there an alternative to storing the password to the LDAP connection in plain text, or refer to an encrypted string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify server.xml. You can define it as a Resource element within your web-app's Context.xml file, assuming you're talking about Tomcat or Glassfish, as you seem to be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please detail how this would be done, or point me to a resource where I could get further instructions?